# Excel VBA Cell Referencing , error mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to referencing to a cell using a label. Example while on form1 i have 20 frames , when i click frame1 it must send a value to the label on form2.

```
last = src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
folha = manutencaoexp.Label27.Caption
cellsit = manutencaoexp.Label29.Caption


src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 6) = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folha).Cells(cellsit, 32).Text     'duração
```

When i use this , it  works pretty fine , but as i have 20 ComboBox on Monitorform , when i press a frame it must change to the selected frame ComboBox, and do a cell refencing.

```
src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 6) = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folha).Cells(Monitorform.ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2, 32).Text
```

Comment: Can you assign a string name to the captions?

Comment: Cellsit is assigned to the captions

Comment: The question is unclear to me. To me what you have made (codewise) works fine. Like @Jeeped comment suggests, working with string names assigned to captions it should work.

Comment: That's why i'm getting crazy , it should work , but for some reason i always get some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not (likely) a full answer to your problem, but it can help you work out what part of your code is throwing the error.

You have a single line of VBA code:

```
src.Worksheets("Manutencao").Cells(last + 1, 6) = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(folha).Cells(cellsit, 32).Text     'duração
```

This has many implicit variables and objects that the VBA code has to stack together. While that's not a problem itself, it can make figuring out problems difficult.

I routinely avoid these types of errors by creating intermediate variables, which helps to separate each step. From your line, it would go like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim thisWB As Workbook
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook

    Dim manutencaoWS As Worksheet
    Dim folhaWS As Worksheet
    Set manutencaoWS = thisWB.Sheets("Manutencao")
    Set folhaWS = thisWB.Sheets(folha)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim folha As String
    Dim cellsit As Long

    lastRow = manutencaoWS.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    folha = manutencaoexp.Label27.Caption
    cellsit = manutencaoexp.Label29.Caption

    Dim folhaText As String
    folhaText = folhaWS.Cells(cellsit, 32)

    manutencaoWS.Cells(last + 1, 6) = folhaText
End Sub
```

It may seem that you're taking lots of extra steps to accomplish the same line of code, but breaking out each step like this makes it more readable and understandable -- and easier to isolate an error.

Also, **please** always use [`Option Explicit`](http://www.riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-).

Comment: Keeping with the same problema , cellsit = 0 , is it possible the problem to be on `cellsit = manutencaoexp.Label29.Caption` or maybe switch `manutencaoexp.Label29.Caption = "Monitorform.ComboBox2.ListIndex + 2"` to this `manutencaoexp.Label29.Caption = Monitorform.ComboBox2.ListIndex + 2`